# how do you unselect all items from a listbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, listbox

is there a way to unselect all items of a listbox using jquery without looping through each item?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

jQuery is designed to work with multiple elements at the same time:

```
$(listboxSelector).find("option").attr("selected", false);
```

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Reset-Clear-ListBox-selection-selected-values-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 28):

The shortest way is this method:

```
$("#myListBox").val([]);
```

This sets the value to an empty array, meaning select no values.  [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) takes an array in the case of a `<select multiple>` element.  Note that `$("select").val('');​​​​​​​` also works here :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#myListbox option').attr('selected',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mylistbox").options.attr("selected", false);
```